# Use to tamil font in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress

How can I use Tamil font in my WordPress blog. The blog I need help with is [jsabdul.wordpress.com](http://jsabdul.worpress.com). The tamil font like as baamini, suntommy..etc.,

Answer (score 1):

1- Download some free Tamil fonts such as

http://ta.wikipedia.org/s/3m

2- Create a version that you can use on the web with FontSquirrel

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

3- Insert the @font-face statement in the CSS and upload the fonts on the web

4- Change the font families in the CSS to match the Tamil fonts.

To  do this, you need to be able to edit a CSS file and to use an FTP software.

Info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Playing_With_Fonts#Font_Face